# Particles are not dropping down in blender 2.8 beta

Tags: modifiers, particles

I am creating a scene in blender 2.8 and I want raindrops in that scene but when I use a particle system to simulate raindrops, all drops are going in different directions rather than dropping down.[image: first]

[image]

Comment: That is odd. You could try going (in the Particles panel) to Physics/Deflection and defining the Collision Collection as the collection that they are in, e.g. road, to make sure they aren't interacting with something in another collection.

Comment: Please use the [Edit] link at the bottom of your question and show the physics settings for the particles

Comment: Does the scene properties have gravity turned on and a z-value? Is the physics type set to none? Is the gravity field weight set to 0.0?

Comment: thanks for your support but the problem is now gone, it occurs because of a force field.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm having the exact same problem now. I'm trying to let snow fall inside an 8 cm glass sphere. All values mentioned by @sambler are checked. Gravity on 1, physics Newtonian, gravity's on and has a negative z-value, but nothing's happening.
Could this be a scale problem? I set Normal to -0.011 m /s, since they're supposed to fall that far in one second (may have to turn that up once I can see things happening). Particles are scaled 0.012 of the original size, which looks about right. But nothing moves when i hit "Play". Could there be any setting I'm missing?